# http://localhost:8080/uploads/1616174243802.png 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem with an uploading photo to my website, here is a code which I have, but I have an issue that photo isn't displayed

```
import express from 'express';
import multer from 'multer';
import { isAuth, isAdmin } from '../utils';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/');
  },
  filename(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, `${Date.now()}.png`);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });
const uploadRouter = express.Router();

uploadRouter.post('/', isAuth, isAdmin, upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  res.status(201).send({ image: `/${req.file.path}` });
});
export default uploadRouter;
```

Comment: Does your Express serve static files?

Comment: Please read [ask] to see what is expected in a question. In this case, pay special attention to the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the question" which the current title does not.

Comment: @tadman yes it is.

Comment: Also check that the permissions on your filesystem are correct in the upload directory. It's possible nodejs doesn't have access to the folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));
```

Add this to serve static files from your app ,in your main file (index or main)

Comment: I already have this one, but still don't work

Comment: can you share your directory structure?